# Why is SQL Server 2005 Randomly Truncating Whitespace?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following T/SQL:-

```
create table #temp(foo varchar(10))

insert into #temp select ''
insert into #temp select 'abc'
insert into #temp select ' '

select len(foo) from #temp where foo = '  '

drop table #temp
```

Returns two 0's, despite the fact the criteria means it should return nothing. Additionally it's returning the length of the two whitespace rows, one of which is indeed of length 0 but also one which is of length 1, reporting both as length 0.

Does anybody know what's going on here?!

**Update**: It appears this is related to the ANSI_PADDING database option covered by Microsoft in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation:

Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.

There is a similar function named DataLength that you should become familiar with.

```
create table #temp(foo varchar(10))

insert into #temp select ''
insert into #temp select 'abc'
insert into #temp select ' '

select len(foo), DataLength(foo) from #temp where foo = '  '

drop table #temp
```

Trailing spaces are removed for comparison purposes, too.  You can accommodate this by converting the data to varbinary and comparing it that way.  If you do this, I would leave the original comparison alone (for sargability reasons).

```
create table #temp(foo varchar(10))

insert into #temp select ''
insert into #temp select 'abc'
insert into #temp select ' '

select len(foo), DataLength(foo) 
from    #temp 
where   foo = ' '
        and Convert(varbinary(8), foo) = Convert(VarBinary(8), ' ')

drop table #temp
```

Comment: This seems to apply to where clauses too, anyway of making the where clause not exclude trailing blanks?

Comment: I edited my original response to show a way to filter on a single space.  Hope this helps.